# Vue + Laravel проблема с шаблоном

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Есть Laravel шаблон главной страницы:

```
<div class="page page--index l-container l-mt-20 lm-mt-0 l-pb-20 lm- 
pb-0 l-clear">
<top-bar v-show="showSidebars"></top-bar>
@yield('content')
<right-sidebar v-show="showSidebars"></right-sidebar>
</div>
```

Есть Laravel шаблон со страницей "Контакты". В нем используется другой код:

```
<div class="page page--entry l-wide_container lm-mb-10 lm-mt-0">
</div>
```

Эта страница без сайдбара. При переходе с главной страницы на страницу "Контакты" шаблон не меняется, но если перезагрузить страницу, то работает.

Переход по страницам используется vue-router:

```
    {
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    component: Home
   },

   {
    path: '/contact',
    component: Contact,
    meta: { title: 'Contact' }
   },
```

Как решить данную проблему, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу заново рендерилось тело страницы без перезагрузки, т.к. меню вверху сайта одинаковое на всех страницах, т.е. перезагрузка дива с `page page--index l-container l-mt-20 lm-mt-0 l-pb-20 lm- 
pb-0 l-clear` на `page page--entry l-wide_container lm-mb-10 lm-mt-0`